# Firebase confusing profiles on a phone

Tags: android, firebase

I am making an application that uses firebase. My problem is that if a user creates 2 profiles on a single device, the profile pictures get mixed up. I think this is because of caching. I am also making use of Picasso to load the images, I am aware that they also have caching functionality, but I do not know if the caching itself is the issue and not some mix up from the authentication.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and i solved it by changing `Picasso` with `Glide`.

Add in `dependencies` of your `build.gradle` (Module:app) this line:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

and than use it in your code like this:

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(profilePhotoUrl).centerCrop().transform(new CircleTransform(getApplicationContext())).override(45,45).into(userProfilePhoto);
```

Hope it helps.